# Manga where the main character is reincarnated as a noble and his fiancée a princess; he becomes her bodyguard

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I think the story went like this: the main character is reincarnated as a noble after two lives (as swordsman and Sage), and his fiancée is a princess. He then kicked her out because he has no job level (because of his other lives). After that, he rescues the princess along the way, and becomes her bodyguard.

Comment: I have a couple quick questions, how long ago was it that you read this?  so far i have found a handful of manga that don't quite match, so how certain of the details are you?  you might want to look here https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337 to see if it has anything that will help improve your question

Answer (score 4):

The closest match I have been able to find is *[Dekisokonai to Yobareta Moto Eiyuu wa, Jikka Kara Tsuihousareta no de Suki Katte ni Ikiru Koto ni Shita](https://mangadex.org/title/39854/dekisokonai-to-yobareta-moto-eiyuu-wa-jikka-kara-tsuihousareta-no-de-suki-katte-ni-ikiru-koto-ni-shita/chapters/)*, also known as *"The Former Hero was Called as a Failure and Expelled From His Home, Decided to Live on His Own"*.

The manga starts out with the main character, who is a noble, being kicked out because he is a "failure".  He is considered a failure because he gains no gift, or special skill, during a ceremony.  He didn't gain any gift because he already had them from his past life as a hero.  After leaving the house, he encounters his fiancée and her bodyguard being attacked. After defeating the monster attacking them, he requests to be another bodyguard for her.

While the translation I found doesn't explicitly call the fiancée a princess, the bodyguard thinks that she is about to fail the duty entrusted to her by the king when the fiancée is being attacked. Also, the fiancée mentions being a part of the royal family.

The main differences between this manga and the question are the reason the main character was kicked out was the lack of a "gift" rather than job level, and the main character was previously only a hero, rather than a swordsman and sage.  The gift versus job level could be a difference in translation, or a mix-up with another manga.  As for the Hero vs Swordsman and Sage, the only ones I could find that had the double reincarnation did not have the main character as a noble, so no fiancée or getting kicked out.

Answer (score 0):

I have one where he's reincarnated twice after being a sage and a swordsman, but those are the only similarities.

It's called *[Nido Tensei shita Shounen wa S-Rank Boukensha Toshite Heion ni Sugosu: Zense ga Kenja de Eiyuu Datta Boku wa Raise dewa Jimi ni Ikiru](https://myanimelist.net/manga/120612/Nido_Tensei_shita_Shounen_wa_S-Rank_Boukensha_Toshite_Heion_ni_Sugosu__Zense_ga_Kenja_de_Eiyuu_Datta_Boku_wa_Raise_dewa_Jimi_ni_Ikiru)*.

Comment: So in the manga you're talking about, the main character doesn't become a bodyguard for a princess?